# Confidence interval for variance for normal distribution

Tags: normal-distribution, confidence-interval, inference

Suppose I have observations $a_{1},...,a_{n}$ of $X_{1},...,X_{n}$ independent $\mathcal{N}(m_{1}, m_{2})$-distributed random variables, where $m_{1}=E(X_{i})$ and $m_{2}=Var(X_{i})$, $i=1,...n$. How do I construct a $95$% upper bounded confidence interval for $\frac{1}{\sqrt(m_{2})}$?

Comment: Why not use a bootstrap estimate and make your life easier?

Comment: Just compute the CI for $m_2$ and transform it.  This is a standard, textbook calculation (involving the chi-squared distribution), so you'll have no trouble implementing it (or even computing it by hand).

Comment: Yes, the transformation part and the basic calculations I can do. The problem is that I do not fully understand the question as $m_{2}$ seem to depend on the $X_{i}$, and are thus potentially different for each $X_{i}$(??). Sorry for being unclear.

Comment: From my Answer, I hope you see how the exact CI using a chi-squared distribution works. // If you want to know about bootstrap CIs, I could show you examples of two kinds. One assuming you know data are normal, and one with no assumption data re normal. Have you seen _any_ kind of bootstrap before? // Sometime you should learn about bootstrapping, but _when_ is up to you.

Comment: Yes, your answer was very clear and easy to follow. Thanks for that! No, I haven't seen bootstrapping before. I guess I should learn about it at some point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In more traditional notation, which you're more likely to
encounter if you look on the internet or in various textbooks,
suppose $X_1, X_2, \dots, X_n$ is a random sample from
$\mathsf{Norm}(\mu, \sigma)$ and you seek a 95% CI for the
population variance $\sigma^2,$ where neither $\mu$ norm $\sigma$ is known.

The relationship to the chi-squared distribution mentioned
in comments is:
$$\frac{(n-1)S^2}{\sigma^2} \sim \mathsf{Chisq}(\nu = n-1),$$
where $\sigma^2$ is estimated by $S^2 = \frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^n (X_u - \bar X)^2$ and $\mu$ is estimated by $\bar X = \frac 1n\sum_{i=1}^n X_i.$

From it, you can use printed tables of chi-squared distributions or
software to find $L$ such that
$$P\left(L \le \frac{(n-1)S^2}{\sigma^2}\right)
= P\left(\sigma^2 \le \frac{(n-1)S^2}{L}\right) = 0.95.$$

Each new dataset will have its own value of $\bar X,$ used in the computation of $S^2.$ But once you find the sample variance $S^2,$ your confidence bound is determined; you have only to compute it.

Here is an example, using a sample of size $n = 50$ from
a normally distributed population which has $\mu=100,$  $\sigma=15,$ and $\sigma^2 = 225.$ For this particular sample you get the 95% upper bound $365.3.$ [In a real application you wouldn't know the true values of $\mu$ and $\sigma,$ but in this simulation, you know that this is one of the 95% of bounds that is correct.]

```
set.seed(810)
x = rnorm(50, 100, 15)
summary(x); length(x);  sd(x);  var(x)

   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  66.13   90.98  101.76  100.48  109.32  136.47 
[1] 50          sample size
[1] 15.90439    # sample SD
[1] 252.9496    $ sample variance

49*var(x)/qchisq(.05, 49)
[1] 365.2939
```

With a larger sample, you have more information and you typically get a bound that is closer to the actual value of $\sigma = 15^2=225.$ Using the same population with $n = 500$ observations, I got the bound $283.9.$

```
set.seed(2020)
x = rnorm(500, 100, 15)
499*var(x)/qchisq(.05, 499)
[1] 283.9234
```

*Notes:* (1) To get an upper confidence bound for $\frac{1}{\sqrt{\sigma^2}} = \frac{1}{\sigma},$ start with $U$ such that $P\left(\frac{(n-1)S^2}{\sigma^2} \le U\right) =
P\left(\frac{1}{\sigma^2} \le \frac{U}{(n-1)S^2}\right) = 0.95$ to get a confidence bound for $1/\sigma^2$ and then take the square root.

(2) Reasons to use the chi-squared method are that it is exact for normal data and requires minimal computation. By contrast, bootstrap methods (suggested in a comment) are approximate and computationally intensive.

Nevertheless, bootstrap CIs are useful when
the type of population distribution is unknown or where theoretical derivations lead to difficult computations. I tried a couple of types of bootstrap methods for your
Question--with reasonably good approximate results.

For bootstrap demonstrations below, recall my example above with $n = 50$ random observations with sample
variance $S^2_{obs} = 252.95$ and 95% chi-squared bound $365.29.$

If you do not know that data are normal, you might use a **nonparametric bootstrap.** We take 're-samples' of size $n=50$ from data `x` (*with* replacement). For each re-sample find sample variance $S^2_{re}$ and ratio
`r.re` $= S^2_{re}/S^2_{obs},$ comparing re-sampled variance with observed variance.

With $5000$ such ratios,
we have an ideal how large the population variance $\sigma^2$ relative to the observed sample variance. Then we use quantile 0.025 of the `r.re`'s to get a 95% upper bound $373.1,$ which is a little larger than the result $365.29$ from the chi-squared method.

```
set.seed(810);  x = rnorm(50, 100, 15)
v.obs = var(x);   v.obs
[1] 252.9496
# nonpar boot
set.seed(2020)
r.re = replicate(10^5, var(sample(x,50,rep=T))/v.obs)
L = quantile(r.re, .05)
v.obs/L
      5% 
373.1255
```

If you believe data are normal, but do not know about the chi-squared method (amnesia? ignorance? laziness?), you could use a **parametric bootstrap.** The major difference is that re-samples are not from `x` but are normal samples 'suggested by `x`" (using the observed sample mean and variance).

This amounts to approximating the normal-theory distribution of $S^2$ by
numerical means. With a million iterations (trying to minimize simulation error), we get a 95% upper bound $365.31,$
which is essentially identical to
the exact result $365.29.$

```
set.seed(810);  x = rnorm(50, 100, 15)
v.obs = var(x);  a.obs = mean(x)
v.obs
[1] 252.9496
# param boot
r.re = replicate(10^6,var(rnorm(50,a.obs,sqrt(v.obs)))/v.obs)
L = quantile(r.re, .05)
v.obs/L
      5% 
365.3132
```